# Flutter: FLog and Logger

Tags: flutter, logging

I am new in flutter and I am building an app in flutter and looking for logging options. I know there are several logging packages available like logger and flog. These loggers logs in console, but how these can working in production. In production there is no console and how I can debug the app if I don't have access to log files. Do i need to store logs to local storage and have ability to export these files.
Please advise.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check out Firebase Analytics which should allow you to collect logs on devices in production and view them from from the web console, along with a ton of other useful information.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/overview